# $f(x) = f(\frac{1}{x})$ for all $x$ $\implies $ $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}f'(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I think this can be shown using the chain rule, but I'm not confident that equality of functions implies equality of derivatives.

Assume continuity. Then we have

$D_xf(\frac{1}{x}) = f'(\frac{1}{x}) (-\frac{1}{x^2})$ using $f(\frac1x) = f(g(x))$ with $g(x) = \frac1x$ and then chain rule

Comment: Equality of functions *certainly* implies equality of derivatives; after all, the derivative is nothing more than some limit involving difference quotients of the underlying function.

Comment: how can that equality hold for all $x?$

Comment: @T.Bongers Even if a function has jumps or other weird things (i.e. if there are non-differentiabilities, they will be non-differentiable at the same points and where the derivatives exist they will always be equal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'$ is discussed, then I assume that $f$ is differentiable on its domain. As a side note, its domain is ***not*** the set of real numbers. (Can you see why?) Thus, it is perhaps inappropriate to say "for **all** $x$," but I'll put that aside.

Now, putting $g(x)=\frac1x,$ we have that $f(x)=(f\circ g)(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f.$ Applying Chain Rule (the hypotheses of which I leave to you to verify) does, indeed, give us $$f'(x)=f'\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\cdot g'(x)=f'\left(\frac1x\right)\cdot\frac{-1}{x^2}=-\frac1{x^2}f'\left(\frac1x\right).$$

Comment: Is what you mean by the domain can't be the set of all real numbers that The domain can include everything but $0$, because $\frac{1}{0}$ is not valid?

Comment: Precisely. There *are* arithmetic systems in which $\frac10$ is sensible, but not the real number system, and a number of familiar basic arithmetic properties break in such systems, so derivatives might not work the same way, either.